# c#: Linq with Dictionary with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

So i have `List` of `Dictionary<string, object>`
And i want to parse 1 item with condition of 2 column names:

If i search for 1 item with column name "Id" i do it this way:

```
var collection ....

var result = collection.OfType<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .SelectMany(d => d.Where(x => x.Key == "id"))
    .Where(x => x.Value?.ToString() == "1234")
    .ToList();
```

Here i am search for item with column name `Id` that its value is `1234` and this works fine.

Now i want to add some condition:

I want to search for an item with column name `Id` and value `1234` and column name `"Class"` and i want to get the `"Class"` column name value.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Last part of your question is bit confusing. Showing input and expected output in tabular form helps.

Comment: It looks like item of your collection is dynamic object with property names in keys, and their values in value (very high chance that you just incorrectly deserialized JSON or something), so instead of selecting concrete properties I would recommend you to convert this dictionary to DTO, and then perform state-of-art selection and filtering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamentally your `SelectMany` is flattening all the entries from *all* the dictionaries. That means by the time you get the key/value pairs, you don't know which pair came from which dictionary. You don't want to do this in the case you've described. You want to filter to specific items, then select one aspect of each item.

You could just use the code below. I'm assuming that `collection` is of type `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`, so you don't need the `OfType` call you've got at the moment.

```
var result = collection
    // Filter to items with the correct ID.
    .Where(d => d.TryGetValue("Id", out var id) && id?.ToString() == "1234")
    // Filter to items containing a "Class" entry
    .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("Class"))
    // Select the class
    .Select(d => d["Class"])
    .ToList();
```